# Union Type Constructing In Ruby

Tags: ruby

Does Ruby allow for Union Type Constructing pr Cartesian product constructing? I am a extremely new person with Ruby and I can't find the answer anywhere. I know it is dynamically typed so does that mean both are impossible?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Ruby is dynamically typed / untyped / statically unityped / whatever you want to call it.